# Gentoo on Samsung 850 evo

Tags: gentoo, ssd, samsung

I want to use my Samsung 850 evo for Gentoo linux. I have read some posts about problems of evo 850 on linux, but they were about 2 years ago. Are there any problems with this SSD on linux, now? I have the latest firmware on SSD.

Second question, Gentoo's portage make many writting operations on disk, how big ram disk (temp fs) should be? Will 6GB be enough, if i will use it also for browser cache and temp dir of linux? I have 16GB memory.

Third question, are there some "optimisation" settings for linux and portage?

Comment: there's no need to use a ramdisk.  it's far simpler, and more efficient use of memory, to just create a swap partition and then enable zswap in the kernel (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/471912/zram-vs-zswap-vs-zcache-ultimate-guide-when-to-use-which-one).  Configure it to allow up to, say, 50% of RAM to be used as zswap.  This will transparently compress swap, using SSD and/or HDD swap device(s) as backing store when needed.  linux's standard disk buffering will cache recently used files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Samsung 850 on Linux

With the latest SSD firmware, there should not be any problems with the drive. Having the newest BIOS can sometimes help too, so perhaps you should check if there is a newer one.

Regarding your ram disk question: I don't really see why you should really need one, but if you want to influence the maximum size of /tmp/ you can do this.

#### Changing /tmp size on Gentoo with systemd

cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount

nano /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount

=> In the "Options=" line, add a ,size=51200M in the end for a 50GB maximum size of /tmp.

#### Changing /tmp size on Gentoo classic without systemd

nano /etc/fstab

=> edit the line "tmpfs   /tmp..." and add ",size=50G" to the options.

#### Size considerations:

The size you set it to is not terribly important. It will only use RAM for the data that is stored on it. You can set it to 100GB on a 16GB system. Might not make much sense, but will usually not cause problems unless you actually try to put so much data in there! A more sensible size will probably be something slightly below 16GB, maybe 12GB or 14GB. Maximum size should probably not be bigger than system ram + size of swappartition/swapfile.

Comment: Do not make the tmpfs size greater than (RAM + swap - 2GB).  If it fills up, the OOM killer can't fix it and the system will deadlock.